# Download PDF file from Web location and Prompt user SaveAs box on client in web-Application ASP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, client-side

I have link of a PDF file located on a website e.g. (https://www.mysite.com/file.pdf).
What I need is prompt the user (on Client side) the SaveAs box to choose the file location to save the file.

I tried the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , but got know that it is only for Windows Forms. and my application is web based.

**C# Code**

```
var fileNumber = lblFileNumber.Text;
string fileDownloadLink = "http://www.mysite.com/" + fileNumber + ".pdf";
string fileName = fileNumber + ".pdf";
bool exist = false;
try
   {
      var request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(fileDownloadLink);
      using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
       {
          exist = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
       }
   }
catch
   {
   }

if (exist)
   {
    var wClient = new WebClient();
    wClient.DownloadFile(fileDownloadLink, fileName);
   }
```

I wrote the above code, it does check if the file is exist on the file location, but

**how to prompt user to choose the location to where he want to save file and save on his local hard drive?**

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do that. When the user wants to download a file, the browser will decide how to show it to the user.

Write a file from disk directly:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(@"C:\yourfile.pdf");
```

Or from another source, loaded as a byte array:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytesOfYourFile);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: You mean that the client cannot download the file directly from the web site?

Comment: You cannot show a Windows Forms (or any other) control on the client. Instead use the 'web way of working' by delivering the file to the browser in the decent way.

Comment: So how to perform this task? because the link you have mention in your message said "Write something that works for ASP.NET"

Comment: There is a solution from someone else, but I will put my implementation in my post.